# Why does zig function not accept null as function argument when type signature specifies parameter as nullable?

Tags: zig

This is my zig code. I am just trying to read a file line by line

```
pub fn main() anyerror!void {
    const path = "/home/testdata/testfile";
    var f = try fs.openFileAbsolute(path, .{.mode = fs.File.OpenMode.read_only});
    defer f.close();
    debug.print("{any}\n", .{f});
    debug.print("{any}\n", .{fs.cwd()});

    var reader = f.reader();
    var output: [500]u8 = undefined;
    var output_fbs = std.io.fixedBufferStream(&output);
    const writer = output_fbs.writer();
    while(true) {
        reader.streamUntilDelimiter(writer, "\n", null) catch |err| {
            debug.print("{any}\n", .{err});
            break;
        };

        var b = output_fbs.getWritten();
        debug.print("{any}\n", .{b});
    }
}
```

Now this fails to build with this unhelpful error message saying

```
main.zig:35:51: error: expected type 'u8', found '*const [1:0]u8'
        reader.streamUntilDelimiter(writer, "\n", null) catch |err| {
```

But the signature of steamUntilDelimiter is as follows `streamUntilDelimiter(self: Self, writer: anytype, delimiter: u8, optional_max_size: ?usize) (...)`

If `optional_max_size` can be null then why won't it accept null as an argument and why does the error message say that I have provided a `*const [1:0]u8` is it casting the null into that?

I even tried it with a number instead of null but i get the same error

```
main.zig:35:51: error: expected type 'u8', found '*const [1:0]u8'
        reader.streamUntilDelimiter(writer, "\n", 100) catch |err| {
                                                  ^~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read error carefully. it points to the second argument (`"\n"`), which accepts a `u8` (character) not `[]const u8` (string). you can write the character inside single quotes (`'\n'`)

Comment: thank you, the `^` below the third argument threw me off.

Comment: that looks like compiler bug. you should file an issue in https//github.com/ziglang/zig/

Comment: i did https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/16525